# Запись данных до таблицы в mysql используя питон

Tags: python, mysql

Пытаюсь записать в дб массив с данными но выбивает ошибка

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters: str(25.03.2024), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

**массив выглядит так**

```
values = ['25.03.2024', 0, 2, 'oblačno', -2, 0, 'zamračené', 5, 8, 'oblačno', 1, 3, 'polojasno', 1.625, 2.875, 'o7dni', 7]
```

**и код который вкладывает его так**

```
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO weather_forecast (date, min_temperature_night, max_temperature_night, state_at_night, min_temperature_morning, max_temperature_morning, state_at_morning, min_temperature_day, max_temperature_day, state_at_day, min_temperature_evening, max_temperature_evening, state_at_evening, average_temperature, average_cloudiness, kedy, 7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 7)"
cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, values)
```

Как это можно решить?

Comment: [MySQLCursor.executemany() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) Особое внимание - формированию массива параметров (первый пример, переменная `data`). PS. С точки зрения MySQL значение `'25.03.2024'` не является валидным литералом даты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany` ожидает **список списков**, а вы передаёте просто список. В результате значение `"25.03.2024"` интерпретируется как список параметров, которые нужно подставить во все ожидаемые значения одной строки обращения к `SQL`, естественно ничего не получается. Если вы хотите вставить одну строку значений, то используйте просто `execute`:

```py
cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, values)
```

Либо, если вы всё-таки хотите вставить не одну строку данных, а много, то можете использовать `executemany`, но и в данных должен быть список списков:

```py
values = [
    ['25.03.2024', 0, 2, 'oblačno', -2, 0, 'zamračené', 5, 8, 'oblačno', 1, 3, 'polojasno', 1.625, 2.875, 'o7dni', 7],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Только я внутри массива написал круглые скобки и у меня заработало. Спаибо!

Comment: @KostyaKhmylov Круглые скобки - это кортеж, можно и так, да )